# Want Sunspot/Solr order_by :random to remain consistent for the session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am using the Sunspot gem for Solr integration with a Rails 3.2 application. My search is heavily parameterized, so instead of sorting by relevancy, I sort by default using order_by(:random).

The problem is some features of the application return the user to the search results page (e.g., after signing in), but since the sorting is not consistent, the results have changed on return. In some contexts, it's just plain broke.

Is there a proper Sunspot way to "lock" the random field for a user's session? Or do I have to deconstruct the code and make a patch?